# Dockerize a Typescript MERN monorepo that uses pnpm workspaces

Tags: typescript, docker, mern, monorepo, pnpm

I have a project with the following folder structure, it's a typescript monorepo that has two apps (client and api) and a shared library (shared), both the backend and the frontend depend on the shared library. And I want to dockize this project.

```
my-monorepo/
|-- api/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- tsconfig.json
|  
|
|-- client/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- tsconfig.json
|   
|
|-- shared/
|   |-- src/
|   |-- package.json
|   |-- tsconfig.json
|
|-- package.json
|-- pnpm-lock.yaml
|-- pnpm-workspace.yaml
|-- tsconfig.base.json
```

I tried putting a Dockerfile in all workspaces and use docker-compose to build all containers, but I got the following error:

```
 > [api 5/7] RUN pnpm install:
2.649  ERR_PNPM_WORKSPACE_PKG_NOT_FOUND  In : "@cybersec/shared@workspace:*" is in the dependencies but no package named "@cybersec/shared" is present in the workspace
2.649
2.649 This error happened while installing a direct dependency of /usr/src/app
2.649
2.649 Packages found in the workspace:
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

The files:

```
# /api/Dockerfile
# Use a Node.js 18 base image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install

# Copy source code
COPY src ./src

# Build TypeScript
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port your app will run on
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run your application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
# /client/Dockerfile
# Use a Node.js base image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install

# Copy source code
COPY src ./src

# Build TypeScript and React app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port your app will run on
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run your application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - project-network
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - shared
      - db

  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    networks:
      - project-network
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - shared
      - api

  shared:
    build:
      context: ./shared

  db:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - project-network
    container_name: mongo-db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

networks:
  project-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Please provide the Docker Compose file you use, and the relevant Dockerfile

Comment: If you have a monorepo, the way I've always done to build my containers is to use the base of the monorepo as the context for the build. Then use a multistage build to bundle the part you are interested in into some dist folder and copy only the bundled part over to your final image.

Comment: If your bundle step doesn't allow that you can use something like turborepos `prune --scope` to get an isolated version of all the parts of your monorepo that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538141/dockerize-a-typescript-mern-monorepo-that-uses-pnpm-workspaces#comment136696930_77538141) by [super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super), a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) cab help. It would allow for bundling only the necessary parts of each application (API and client) into separate images.

Meaning, you would use an initial stage to install dependencies and build the application, followed by a final stage to copy only the necessary files into a smaller image.

##### `/api/Dockerfile` Example

```
# Builder stage
FROM node:18-alpine as builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Copy the entire monorepo
COPY . .

# Install dependencies and build
RUN pnpm install --filter @your-workspace/api...
RUN pnpm run build --filter @your-workspace/api...

# Final stage
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy built files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/api/dist /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/shared /usr/src/app/shared

# Install runtime dependencies only
RUN pnpm install --prod --filter @your-workspace/api...

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

The client Dockerfile would be similar, adjusting the paths and commands to fit the client application.

The `docker-compose.yml` remains largely unchanged, but makes sure it uses the Dockerfiles correctly.
(Do replace `@your-workspace` with the actual name of your workspace):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - project-network

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    networks:
      - project-network

  db:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - project-network
    container_name: mongo-db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

networks:
  project-network:
    driver: bridge
```